# Removing low poly cylinders edges?

Tags: edges

I've done some searching and didn't turn up an appropriate answer (I could have missed it) to my problem.

This is for a game, so the ingame mesh must be a low poly model, but I'm trying to make it look like the high poly model via normal maps.

The issue I'm having is that ingame the mesh has all the qualities of the high poly, but you also get the edges and faces of the low poly, which makes it look terrible.

Is there any way to remove or smooth those edges without destroying the shape of the low poly so that I can achieve a high quality ingame mesh without having to have a million edges?

[image: low poly vs high]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to Say, 'How to remove Flat Edges'.
If you want Low poly But smooth Cylinder then;

1. Select The Cylinder & In Tool Shelf Click 'Smooth'
   [image]

(It's A low-poly cylinder with only 24 Faces on curved Surface.)

[image]

2. Go to Modifiers Tab Add Edge Split Modifier To get the Caps Splited Rest of the Cylinder. This wont Split The Faces on Curved Surface. Because They Are Attached with a higher angle although you can split them in some cases by increasing the Angle of Edge Split Modifier. But I think 30 Degree will work.

[image]

You Will get Smooth Cylinder with this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I believe that's exactly what I need. Will try it after work. Would loop cuts be needed to maintain the sharp edges we're the case bends?

Comment: No, In subdivision loop cuts are added to maintains the sharp edge but not in smooth.If you want some of the hard edges try altering the Degree of Edge Split.

Comment: Just wanted to say I tested this out and it's exactly what I needed! Thank you so much.